# How to Use Javascript's Fetch to get POST Request Data?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to make a POST request using Javascript's `fetch` method as described [here](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch).

I get a `ReadableStream` instead of a usual `json` response, such as what I would get with jQuery, Angular, whatever.

My code is here: https://jsbin.com/vuwilaviva/edit?css,js,output

```
var request = new Request('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'POST', 
    mode: 'cors',
    data: 'The sky is green',
    redirect: 'follow',
    headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    })
});


// Now use it!
fetch(request).then(function(resp) {
  console.log('Logging response...')
  console.log(resp);
});
```

The test API endpoint works fine with postman, curl, etc, so I am sure I am using `fetch` wrong, and it's not an issue with the API (it just returns whatever string is passed to it as `data`):

[image]

**Edit**: The current answer doesn't actually get the data returned by the post request - it's nowhere to be found in the logged `json`:

[image]

Comment: You pass data in the `body` property.

Comment: That link tells you how to get JSON from the response, in the section with the header **Handling JSON**...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try something else that it details on that page? You seem to be a bit confused as to how exactly JSON is used. Your last edit shows what was returned in the Postman result above it, as a JavaScript object, which is what JSON is meant to provide. If you don't want JSON, but just want text, see the section with the header **Handling Basic Text/HTML Responses** *just below the section I pointed to you*...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Changing response type to text just gets me the json object as text. I still don't see the data I need. And yes, I did try what you pointed me to.

Comment: I would suggest using your browser's developer tools, or something like Fiddler to look at the network traffic and see if the headers or anything else is different between when you use AJAX and when you use the Fetch API.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yea, thanks, I will figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

response.json should be used for this

```
fetch(request)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log(json));
```

Comment: fun fact: you can now use `.then(console.log)` in chrome, maybe others (they fixed `this`)

Comment: @pethel: Two things here - 1. This doesn't get me what I need - I don't see the response string in the json. 2. Can you explain your answer, why the two then statements? Isn't the call already async, why is the response a stream?

Comment: @VSO your issue is the contenttype response.json() -> response.text() now and you can log the content as text. Try to change to application/json but you also need to adjust your server code because.

Comment: @pethel My "backend" is the test API here http://httpbin.org/. It works just fine using anything by fetch, so I don't imagine that's the problem, unless I don't understand some implementation detail.

Comment: @VSO https://jsbin.com/cedaxabida/edit?css,js,output , hope you see the update. I changed the headers.

Comment: I am looking to get "The sky is green" from the API, I am not seeing it. I might just be blind, in which case, I really apologize - I do appreciate the help. @pethel

Comment: @VSO but  "The sky is green"  is what you are trying to send to the server. What the server returns to you is another story. In this case something like this https://httpbin.org/get (open in browser)

Comment: @pethel: See my POSTMAN screenshot. It sends back "The sky is green". I tell it what to send back because it's an API specifically for testing.

Comment: @pethel: That's cool, I appreciate your help, I will figure out and come back to accept your answer.